# Laravel Cashier - Updating the Payment Method of a Subscription

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to figure out how to update the Stripe payment method associated with a subscription.

Is it fine if I simply update the default payment method of the user ?

I would use Stripe's JS to get the card information and make a payment method token with it, then update the default payment method server side. Would that be ok ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that's correct - follow https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse to create and save a Payment Method to a Customer for future use. After which, pass the newly created Payment Method in  invoice_settings.default_payment_method[0].

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method